# prevent the combo box from changing its value

Tags: javascript, jsp, combobox

I have 4 Combo boxes, attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4
Based on one the other will be painted in jquery Ajax.

Requirement is

if attr1 size is 1 automatically attr2 should be loaded,if attr2 size is 1 then attr3 should be loaded, but if attr2 size is greater than 1 value, then a value in combo is selected and attr3 are loaded.like wise the other two also should be done.

How to prevent the combo box from changing its value load the next combo?? is there any events to prevent the selection but a call to js function should be done??

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post some code or what you have tried e.g.

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(
  function()
  {
    $('#officeItemList').combobox();    
  });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<head>
<title>jquery.combox example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.dimensions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.combobox.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="officeItemList">
    <option value="1">eraser</option>
    <option value="3">pencil</option>
    <option value="4">ruler</option>
    <option value="5">ink</option>
    <optgroup label="paper types">
        <option value="7">A4 paper</option>
        <option value="8">A3 paper</option>
        <option value="9">letter-sized paper</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="chair types">
        <option value="10">executive</option>
        <option value="11">janitor</option>
        <option value="12">developer</option>
    </optgroup>     
</select>
</body>
```